# Find max value of a dataset using tangent of the curve in R

Tags: r

I'm taking measures for an experiment where I'm interested in the value  of V2 when the R1 measure is the highest. I was just looking for the highest R1 value and then checking its V2 value, but I've been told it's more accurate to get the V2 value when the slope of the tangent of the curve is 0 (derivative of the slope = 0). I've found several and easy ways to do this in R when using functions, but since this is a discrete dataset, I have no clue as how to do it. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Data frame looking like this:

```
> pruebaR
# A tibble: 1,001 x 2
        V2    R1
     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 -0.100  1672.
 2 -0.0991 1668.
 3 -0.0982 1665.
 4 -0.0973 1663.
 5 -0.0964 1662.
 6 -0.0955 1661.
 7 -0.0946 1660.
 8 -0.0937 1659.
 9 -0.0928 1659.
10 -0.0919 1659.
# ... with 991 more rows
```

Plot looking like this:
[I cannot attach pics yet!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on44O.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. It is easier for us to help if you provide the `dput` output of your measurements (use `dput(dataframe)`). Regarding your problem, maybe try to fit a regression model to the discrete points.

Comment: Maybe somebody can help you but leave this page because you don't provide the data.

Comment: Hi boski, thanks for the help. I tried to include the dput, but I have 1001 measurements and I'm not allowed to post more than 30000 characters. I already did a spline but I cannot manage to find the value I'm looking for :/

Comment: One way to approximate a derivative (so you can find where it's ~ 0) is to calculate `(f(x) - f(x - e)) / (x - (x - e))`, where `e` is some small number. If you have a spline, you should be able to generate "predictions" with this, which gives you f(x), and you already have x.

Comment: Thanks for the input bouncyball, but I think that's not how I am supossed to approach it. Since I have a spline, couldn't I just find the point of X at which the derivative of the tangent to the spline equals 0? That's what I am trying to get, but I'm not familiar with regressions in R.